# JavaScript not working in Cordova app on Android 4.4+

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, android-webview

I builded a simple test app for Android with Cordova and Intel XDK, and it works perfectly in the emulator in Android 4.0, 4.2, 4.3, but the JavaScript code does not work neither in Android 4.4, nor 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 7.0. Could someone help me to understand what is wrong ? Thanks. Here is the code:

```
<body>

<script>
    function getText() {
        document.getElementById('replace_text').innerHTML = 'A simple line';
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="getText()">Click here to replace text.</a>
<br />
<div id="replace_text">Here is the text to replace.</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you added this line in your MainActivity.java?

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**

Jquery.
What you need to do is download the jquery and link local and add a script file where you add this:

```
var getText = function () {
  $('#replace_text').html('A simple line');
};

var init = function () {
    $('#clickMeToDoSomething').on('click',getText)
};

$(document).ready(init());
```

And that will be your HTML then:

```
<body>
    <a href="#" id="clickMeToDoSomething">Click here to replace text.</a>
            <br/>
            <div id="replace_text">Here is the text to replace.</div>
</body>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to add this line in MainActivity.java (at line 31), and it resulted il a fail while building with Cordova CLI :
" MainActivity.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) "

But I found something similar in SystemWebViewEngine.java :
" // Enable JavaScript
        final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); "
Thus, JavaScript is supposed to be already enabled. But when I try to run the app in Android 4.4+, my JS code doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know Jquery?

Comment: Yes, just a little bit.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Tested in emulator with Android 4.0, 4.4 and 5.0. Thanks an lot! jQuery works perfectly on all these Android versions. But now the question is : if I want to add JavaScript code downloaded from the net (such as for a CSS3/JS menu template), how to convert it into jQuery code? Or, is there any way to run a JS code via jQuery?

Comment: I think personly that the onclick methode don't work in android. Can you give my an example of any JS code that would like to use or what kind of app you would like to make? Maybe I can help you. Do you want maybe to use bootstrap?

Comment: I would like to make a HTML5 hybrid app. To do so, I use Intel XDK. When reading about Intel XDK, I saw that the App Designer component has been retired, although it was helpful to work with UI frameworks (Bootstrap, Framework7, jQuery Mobile, ...). This discouraged me on using a framework. But I'm going to take a look at Bootstrap, on your advise.

Comment: It is possible to use Bootstrap in HTML5 hybride app. I have made [this app] (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=checker.coin.crypto.wingcrony.by.cryptocoinchecker) with bootstrap. So if you have any questions just ask. I also don't use Intel XDK or Cordova

Comment: I saw your app. It's interesting. You don't use XDK nor Cordova, so which tool do you use instead ?

Comment: I don't use any tools just a android studio it's all where I write my main activity where I load the first web page then it's all Js and html

Comment: Okay. Please, I asked another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121852/save-a-web-page-with-css-and-images-for-offline-use-in-cordova would you help me there ? Thanks.